# Enabling JavaScript in Android Studio Quick Documentation Window

Tags: android-studio

Navigation links are not available in my Android Studio quick documentation window because JavaScript is disabled. How do I enable it? I'm using Android Studio Flamingo (2022.2.1 Patch 1).

[image: Screenshot of my quick documentation window]